How can I infer types of multiple function's args in TypeScript
const foo = (a: string, b: string) => {
  console.log('foo', a, b);
};

const bar = (a: number, b: number) => {
  console.log('bar', a, b);
};

const factory =
  <M extends typeof foo | typeof bar>(method: M) =>
  (...args: Parameters<M>) => {
    method(...args);
  };

I want to make multiple function's factory (has different args)
But TypeScript throw an error below message.
A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.
Is Parameters utillity type return tuple?


This appears to be a TypeScript bug to me. It works if you manually make the function M extends (...args: Parameters<typeof foo | typeof bar>) => (ReturnType<typeof foo | typeof bar>).

This is a design limitation as described in ms/TS#47615. The recommended approach is to refactor to be generic in the param list and not the function type, as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz It works perfect! Thank you :D

TypeScript isn't able to understand generic conditional types very well; in particular it can't always look at the Parameters<M> utility type for generic function type M and understand that the output is always spreadable. That's considered a design limitation of TypeScript, as described at microsoft/TypeScript#47615.
According to that issue, the recommended approach is to make the function generic in the argument list A and the return type R of the function type separately. For your code, the return type is always void so we can make it just generic in A:
const factory = <A extends Parameters<typeof foo | typeof bar>>(
    method: (...args: A) => void) => (...args: A) => {
        method(...args);
    };

Because the type A of args is known to be the rest parameter type for method, the call is allowed. And although it's not necessarily important for the example, A has been constrained to Parameters<typeof foo | typeof bar> to prevent you from passing random functions in:
factory(foo)("a", "b"); // okay
factory(bar)(1, 2); // okay
factory((a: string, b: number) => { }) // error!

Playground link to code
